# Create Workspace/Project of RCP (Eclipse) programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, rcp

I want to write maven plugin. I have already RCP aplication that uses org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project object for creating package with files that deploys on server.

I would like to create maven plugin that will automatically create this package. The only problem is that I don't know how to create Workspace/Project object from within java program. I know that it's very problematic because Workspace is created on Eclipse startup. But maybe somebody knows any workaround?

Exception while creating Workspace:

<`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at Main.main(Main.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.InternalPlatform.getOS(InternalPlatform.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.getOS(Platform.java:1168)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.<clinit>(Workspace.java:72)
    ... 6 more`>

I would apreciate any help.

Comment: Only Eclipse plugins and RCPs can access the Workspace and Projects. You can't do this in a plain Java program. You might be able to use a 'headless' Eclipse RCP.

Comment: Is it an option for you to create the project structure and .project file without the rcp eclipse specific API and then simply import the project?  That would be easier to archieve as the RCP dependencies are normally not available during a maven run

Comment: @Iwi A lot of things are checked before packing files. Creating from scratch would take a lot of developing.